# How to replace all cells that starts with in google sheets using python

Tags: python, google-sheets, replace, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to replace all the values in a column which starts with "barcode". However for now, I am able to replace all the values based on the name of the values.

[image]

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('extended-signal-307001- 
4e0bee527c0d.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open('test').sheet1

column_o = wks.findall('barcode recognition error', in_column=15)
print(column_o)

for cell in column_o:
    cell.value = 'barcode error'

wks.update_cells(column_o)
```

Currently, it only replaces if it finds the exact value inside the column which is "barcode recognition error". I want to find the values that starts with "barcode" and replace all those values with "barcode error".

Comment: In your situation, `barcode` and `bar code` should be used as the same value?

Comment: no barcode is different to bar code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to replace the cell value including `barcode` at the top word with `barcode error`.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, I would like to propose to use the batchUpdate method of Sheets API. I thought that when the batchUpdate method is used, your goal can be achieve by one API call. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please use your script for retrieving `credentials`.

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = gc.open('test')
wks = spreadsheet.sheet1
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "findReplace": {
                "find": "^barcode[\\s\\w]+",
                "searchByRegex": True,
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": wks.id,
                },
                "replacement": "barcode error"
            }
        }
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

- In this sample script, all cells in the 1st tab of the Spreadsheet are checked and replaced with `barcode error`. If you want to check the specific column and row, please set the gridRange for `range`.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [FindReplaceRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest)
- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batchupdate#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)

Comment: @Sriram Thank you for your response. About the regex, I thought that in this case, `^barcode.+` can be also used instead of `^barcode[\\s\\w]+`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `recognition error` from the `findall` method and you should be all set.

```
column_o = wks.findall('barcode')
```

Comment: It just shows all the values of barcode. So it will only replace the barcode values. I am trying to replace all the values which starts with "barcode".

Comment: @Sriram could you provide an example of what `wks` looks like?